# how to make poi create excel faster?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

#### problem:

I use poi to create excel. more than 60,000 rows with cellStyle fillin the sheet .It takes me almost 20min+.Please help me to review the code.

#### Improve performance ways:

- How can I improve the performance?
- set the value first and then set the style for each cell?
- Or muti thread support for rows in the same sheet?

#### here is my code:

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SubTaskCenter_Export_User_Sales extends SubTaskCenterAbstract {

    @Autowired
    JielongSlave2_TaskCenterMapper jielongSlave2_taskCenterMapper;

    @Override
    public String getFuncName() {
        return "export_user_sales";
    }

    @Override
    public SXSSFWorkbook export(String sql_id, JSONObject parseObject, Date add_time, Integer wh_id) throws ValidatorException {

        TaskCenterTopicDTO taskCenterTopicDTO = getByTopicAndMchId(parseObject);
        if (null != taskCenterTopicDTO) {
            List<UserSalesDTO> userSalesDTOS = jielongSlave2_taskCenterMapper.userSales(getTopicId(parseObject));
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(userSalesDTOS)) {

                SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();

                CellStyle gCellStyle = createGlobalCellStyle(workbook);

                CellStyle titleRowPickupLineCellStyle = createtitleRowPickupLineCellStyle(gCellStyle, workbook);
                CellStyle titleRowShipCellStyle = createtitleRowShipCellStyle(gCellStyle, workbook);

                CellStyle topicTitleCellStyle = createtopicTitleCellStyle(gCellStyle, workbook);

                CellStyle captainRowCellStyle1 = createcaptainRowCellStyle1(gCellStyle, workbook);
                CellStyle captainRowCellStyle2 = createcaptainRowCellStyle2(gCellStyle, workbook);

                SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Worksheet");

                Map<String, Map<String, List<UserSalesDTO>>> resultMap = userSalesDTOS
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(UserSalesDTO::getP_pickup_line, Collectors.groupingBy(UserSalesDTO::getUid))
                        );

                log.info("[{}] 完成数组处理，开始处理excel", getFuncName());
                int excelRow = 0;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<UserSalesDTO>>> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, List<UserSalesDTO>> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                        int goodsCount = 0;
                        int index = 1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < innerEntry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                            int excelCol = 0;
                            if (i == 0) {
                                SXSSFRow titleRow = sheet.createRow(excelRow);
                                createCellWithBoader(gCellStyle, titleRow);
                                ExcelStyle.mergerColumnByRow(sheet, titleRow, 0, 2);
                                ExcelStyle.mergerColumnByRow(sheet, titleRow, 2, getCol().size());
                                setCellValue(titleRow, 0, titleRowPickupLineCellStyle, userSalesDTOS.get(i).getPickup_line());
                                setCellValue(titleRow, 2, titleRowShipCellStyle, userSalesDTOS.get(i).getPickCode() + " " + userSalesDTOS.get(i).getShipping_area_name());
                                excelRow++;

                                SXSSFRow topicTitleRow = sheet.createRow(excelRow);
                                createCellWithBoader(gCellStyle, topicTitleRow);
                                setCellValue(topicTitleRow, 0, topicTitleCellStyle, taskCenterTopicDTO.getTopic_title());
                                excelRow++;

                                SXSSFRow captainRow = sheet.createRow(excelRow);
                                createCellWithBoader(gCellStyle, captainRow);
                                ExcelStyle.mergerColumnByRow(sheet, captainRow, 1, 3);
                                ExcelStyle.mergerColumnByRow(sheet, captainRow, 3, 7);
                                setCellValue(captainRow, 0, captainRowCellStyle1, "团长");
                                setCellValue(captainRow, 1, captainRowCellStyle1, userSalesDTOS.get(i).getReal_name() + " " + userSalesDTOS.get(i).getUmobile());
                                setCellValue(captainRow, 3, captainRowCellStyle2, "地址： " + userSalesDTOS.get(i).getPickup_address());
                                setCellValue(captainRow, 7, captainRowCellStyle1, "生成时间：" + TimeUtils.format(new Date(), "mm-dd HH:mm"));
                                excelRow++;

                                createTitleColumn(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, excelRow);
                            }
                            excelRow++;

                            SXSSFRow tableRow = sheet.createRow(excelRow);
                            goodsCount = goodsCount + userSalesDTOS.get(i).getGoods_num();
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, trimToEmpty(index));
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, trimToEmpty(userSalesDTOS.get(i).getConsignee()));
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, trimToEmpty(userSalesDTOS.get(i).getMobile()));
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, trimToEmpty(userSalesDTOS.get(i).getOrder_id()));
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, trimToEmpty(userSalesDTOS.get(i).getGoods_name()));
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, trimToEmpty(userSalesDTOS.get(i).getSku()));
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, trimToEmpty(userSalesDTOS.get(i).getGoods_num()));
                            setValueByColAndRow(captainRowCellStyle1, workbook, sheet, tableRow, excelCol++, "  ");
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return workbook;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private CellStyle createcaptainRowCellStyle2(CellStyle gCellStyle, SXSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(gCellStyle);
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        return cellStyle;
    }

    private CellStyle createcaptainRowCellStyle1(CellStyle gCellStyle, SXSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(gCellStyle);
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        return cellStyle;
    }

    private CellStyle createtopicTitleCellStyle(CellStyle gCellStyle, SXSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(gCellStyle);
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        return cellStyle;
    }

    private CellStyle createtitleRowShipCellStyle(CellStyle gCellStyle, SXSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(gCellStyle);
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 20);
        font.setBold(true);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        return cellStyle;
    }


    private CellStyle createtitleRowPickupLineCellStyle(CellStyle gCellStyle, SXSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(gCellStyle);
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 36);
        font.setBold(true);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);
        return cellStyle;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExcelName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ExcelCol> getCol() {
        List<ExcelCol> excelCols = getAbstractColInfo(getFuncName());
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(excelCols)) {
            return excelCols;
        }
        excelCols = new ArrayList<>();
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(0, "序号", 10));
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(1, "取货人", 15));
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(2, "手机", 15));
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(3, "取货编号", 10));
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(4, "商品名称", 50));
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(5, "规格", 50));
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(6, "数量", 10));
        excelCols.add(new ExcelCol(7, "客户签名", 20));
        setAbstractColInfo(getFuncName(), excelCols);
        return excelCols;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) questions are not supported here. And even if, then full code is needed. What is `createCellWithBoader`? What is `ExcelStyle.mergerColumnByRow`? What is `setCellValue`? What is `setValueByColAndRow`? ...

Comment: I would run your code using a profiler and see where it is spending its time -- e.g. Yourkit, jprofiler and I'm sure there are other good ones.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gGSXJYprv7/. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5StTz9WGzG/.

Comment: 130,000 rows.Take me 55min

Comment: Thanks for comment.Wait for reply online

Comment: here is the data：      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eOsgX88lK-dN6TPTbNkHPGrXxQ0BvDh-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I translate this code from Php which uses 5min.Java use 55min ! I can not blieve it

Comment: As per [the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10165), generating 100 columns and 100,000 rows takes max a couple of seconds in Apache POI, see the performance example. You need to profile your code and see which bit of your code is taking the remaining 99.9% of the runtime!

Comment: my library MemPOI export 200_000 rows in about 20 secs. you could use some simple benchmark technique to identify your bottlenecks and then to improve them

Comment: for sure you could avoid assembling DTO only to read their values

Comment: Time is spent on excel, sql only takes 1 second

Comment: Can you show me your code? @firegloves

Comment: you can inspect it, but being a library it could result a bit complex to analyze. however this is the class responsible to generate data rows https://github.com/firegloves/MemPOI/blob/master/src/main/java/it/firegloves/mempoi/Strategos.java